# when I try to destructing the data from react query I am getting Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I am facing issue with react query when I try to destructing the data like this way `const {data: getAllChannelSettingTypes} = useGetAllChannelSettingTypes();` I am gettin this error `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'`

Maybe there is a problem with returning the userQueries

```
const useGetAllChannelSettingTypes = () => {
  const {data: defaultSettingTypes} = useQuery(SETTING_TYPES, () =>
    Api.user.getSettingTypes(),
  );
  const userQueries = useQueries(
    defaultSettingTypes.map((type: any) => {
      return {
        queryKey: ['SETTING_VALUE', type.channelSettingTypeId],
        queryFn: () => Api.user.getSettingValues(type.channelSettingTypeId),
      };
    }),
  );
  console.log(userQueries);
  return userQueries;
};
```

Comment: can you show the output of `console.log(userQueries);` ?

Comment: The problem is useQueries return an array of objects and I was trying to destructure `[{status: 'success', isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, isError: false, isIdle: false, …}
{status: 'success', isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, isError: false, isIdle: false, …}
{status: 'success', isLoading: false, isSuccess: true, isError: false, isIdle: false, …}]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery) useQueries returns an array:

> The useQueries hook returns an array with all the query results.

Each element in the array has these properties:

- status: String
- isIdle: boolean
- isLoading: boolean
- isSuccess: boolean
- isError: boolean
- isLoadingError: boolean
- isRefetchError: boolean
- **data**: **TData, defaults to undefined**.
- dataUpdatedAt: number
- error: null | TError
- errorUpdatedAt: number
- isStale: boolean
- isPlaceholderData: boolean
- isPreviousData: boolean
- isFetched: boolean
- isFetchedAfterMount: boolean
- isFetching: boolean
- isRefetching: boolean
- failureCount: number
- errorUpdateCount: number
- refetch: (options: { throwOnError: boolean, cancelRefetch: boolean }) => Promise
- remove: () => void

So try destructing the data in a loop like this:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < userQueries.length; i++){
  const {data: getAllChannelSettingTypes} = useGetAllChannelSettingTypes()
  // do something with that data of the given query
}
```

If you are only interested in the first result you could do it like this:

```js
const {data: getAllChannelSettingTypes} = useGetAllChannelSettingTypes()[0]
```

Comment: Your code should work, however, I am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')` I understand why this occurred to not setting the initialdata, but could you tell me how to set the default initial data in useQueries?

Comment: As far as I can tell the return value from `useGetAllChannelSettingTypes()` is undefined. You could use this notation to destruct the return value only if it is not undefined:
`const {data: getAllChannelSettingTypes} = useGetAllChannelSettingTypes()[0] || {};`

Answer (score -2):

**try removing the params "data"**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).